# how to set values of textboxes inside a wpf listview?

Tags: c#, wpf

in a WPF application I have a listview with multiple selection allowed with custom numeric up down controls inside a column.

XAML:

```
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Level" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50" >
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtGroupLevel" Width="30" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Century Gothic" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Width="20" Height="50" Margin="5,2.5,0,0">
                                    <Button x:Name="cmdUp" Content="˄" FontWeight="Bold" Height="20" Click="cmdUp_Click" />
                                    <Button x:Name="cmdDown"  Content="˅" FontWeight="Bold" Height="20" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="cmdDown_Click" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Obviously I need the TextBox `txtGroupLevel` to be incremented/decremented when I click the up/down buttons.
What code do I need in the click events of my buttons in order to do that?
thanks for help

Comment: just to make sure, you want to do this all in code-behind and not in a ViewModel?

Comment: In code behind if possible